Convert 6V to 3.3V Battery Schematic (Review and validation)
I’ve been working on a PCB design for a power circuitry prototype using a 4AA battery pack. I’m using the TPS62933 buck converter to step down from 6V to 3.3V and would like to confirm if my schematic is correct and functional. Could anyone please review my schematic and layout? Any suggestions or improvements are greatly appreciated!

Looking forward to your insights!
Thanks in advance for your help.

Looks like it matches the typical application schematic. Where is the PCB layout?

Hi, I just want to review the schematic. Are the current values for the capacitors and Resistors correct?


Per table 7.1, the boost cap should be 100 nF, i.e. 0.1 uF.
Per section 10.2.2.9, an additional 0.1 uF decoupling capacitor on the input is recommended.
The factor K, and therefore Cout, cannot be calculated without load current.
Component selection (ceramic capacitor dielectric type and voltage, inductor construction, etc) and layout are very important in switching regulator design. Be sure to read the datasheet in its entirety to avoid redesigns later.

